# Trying to formalise intuition into a proof that symmetric (hermitian) matrices are diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The other day I stumbled upon LittleO's answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482599/191404). To make reading it easier I did a straight copy-and-paste here:

> Here's some intuition (but not a rigorous proof).
>
> If $A$ is hermitian (with entries in $\mathbb C$), you can easily show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are real and that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.
>
> Typically, all the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct.  (It is in some sense a huge coincidence if two eigenvalues turn out to be equal.) So, typically $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.
>
> Even if $A$ has some repeated eigenvalues, perturbing $A$ slightly will probably cause the eigenvalues to become distinct, in which case there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.  By thinking of $A$ as a limit of slight perturbations of $A$, each of which has an ON basis of eigenvectors, it seems plausible that $A$ also has an ON basis of eigenvectors.

While this idea struck me as very ingenious and intuitive, I'm really having difficulty formalising it into a real proof. The major obstacles are:
1). How to perturb an hermitian $A$ while keeping its eigenvalues distinct? In particular, how to find an hermitian sequence $A_n$ that have distinct eigenvalues and converge to $A$ in some norm? 
2). Based on 1), how to continuously associate the eigenvector family $V_n:=[v_{n,j},j=1,\cdots,d]$ (corresponding to $A_n$, assuming $A_n$ are $d$ by $d$) to $A_n$? Having solved this I would have $V:=[v_j,j=1,\cdots,d]$ (corresponding to $A$) are the limits of $\{v_{n,j},j=1,\cdots,d\}$ respectively and hence $V^HV = \lim_{n\to\infty} V_n^HV_n = I$ and we are done.

Comment: Note that in general, we should not expect the limit of diagonalizable matrices to be diagonalizable.   In particular, note that
$$
\pmatrix{1 + 1/n & 1\\0 & 1}
$$
is diagonalizable for all $n \in \Bbb N$, but its limit is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

In the below, I use $A^*$ to denote the conjugate transpose of $A$.

In truth, I'm not sure how to answer part 1.  In particular, I'm finding it difficult to prove the existence of such a perturbation in such a fashion that doesn't amount to what is essentially a full proof of the spectral theorem.

It is notable, however, that if $\lambda,v$ is an eigenpair of $A$ and $\|v\| = 1$, then the matrix $B = A + \epsilon vv^*$ (where $\epsilon > 0$ can be made arbitrarily small) has "all the same eigenvectors" and will satisfy

- $Bu = Au$ for $u \perp v$
- $Av = (\lambda + \epsilon)v$

Moreover, it is straightforward to show that $A(vv^*) = (vv^*)A$.

---

Assuming that part 1 is accounted for, there is a neat argument for part 2.  Presumably, we have a sequence of Hermitian matrices $A_n \to A$ such that each $A_n$ has distinct eigenvalues, and we have an associated sequence of unitary matrices $U_n$ such that $U_n^*A_nU_n$ is a diagonal matrix.

Notably, *the set of unitary matrices is compact* in $\Bbb C^{d \times d}$.

So, there exists a convergent subsequence $U_{n_k}$.  Let $U$ denote the limit of this subsequence.  Notably, we have $A_{n_k} \to A$, since the subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent with the same limit.  From there, we note that matrix-multiplication and the $A \mapsto A^*$ operator are continuous to conclude that
$$
U^*AU = 
\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} U_{n_k}\right)^*
\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} A_{n_k}\right)
\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} U_{n_k}\right)
\\ 
=
\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} U_{n_k}^*\right)
\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} A_{n_k}\right)
\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} U_{n_k}\right)
\\ 
= \lim_{k \to \infty} (U_{n_k}^*A_{n_k}U_{n_k})
$$
So, $U^*AU$ is the limit of a sequence of *diagonal matrices* in $\Bbb C^{d\times d}$.  Since the set of diagonal matrices is closed in $\Bbb C^{d \times d}$, we may conclude that this limit is also diagonal.  In other words, the Hermitian matrix $A$ is diagonalized by the unitary matrix $U$.

Comment: Even slicker: if $D_{n,B}$ is the set of diagonal matrices with entries bounded by $B$, then $D_{n,B}\times U_n$ is compact, and thus the set of all $U^*DU$ is closed since it's the image of a comapct set under a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify a detail: when you are talking about $\Bbb C^{d\times d}$, what's the topology you're using here? I would assume it is the topology induced by Frobenius norm (i.e. "Entrywise" topology).

Comment: @Vim That works.  As it turns out, every normed topology on $\Bbb C^{d \times d}$ is equivalent to the "entrywise" topology.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer part $(1)$ as part $(2)$ was answered by Omnomnomnom. Consider the space $W$ of Hermitian $n \times n$ matrices as a real vector space (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) and let $D \colon W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the map which maps a Hermitian matrix $A$ to the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. The map $D$ is polynomial in the entries of the matrix $A$ and $D(A) \neq 0$ if and only if the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ are distinct. For example, if $n = 2$, a Hermitian matrix is described as

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} x & a + ib \\ a - ib & y \end{pmatrix} $$

for $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and

$$ D(A) = (x + y)^2 - 4(xy - |a + ib|^2) = (x - y)^2 + (2a)^2 + (2b)^2. $$

Since $D$ is a non-zero polynomial (it doesn't vanish on the diagonal matrices with distinct eigenvalues), the set $\{ A \in W \, | \, D(A) \neq 0 \}$ is [dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025978/the-complement-of-a-zero-set-of-a-polynomial-is-dense) in $W$ so any Hermitian matrix in $D^{-1}(0)$ can approximated by Hermitian matrices with distinct eigenvalues.

In fact, one can show that the set $D^{-1}(0)$ of Hermitian matrices with a repeated eigenvalue is of codimension three in $W$ (see "avoidance of crossings" in Lax's Linear Algebra) but I don't know how to do it without the spectral theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Density is sufficient here.

Comment: I think the space of hermitians should be $n(n-1)/2$-dimensional instead.

Comment: @Vim: You can see that your dimension count is false already for $n = 2$. A Hermitian matrix depends on $n$ real parameters (diagonal entries $a_{ii}$) and $1 + 2 + \dots + (n-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ complex parameters $a_{ij}$ for $i > j$ which results in a total of $n + 2 \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = n^2$ real parameters.

Comment: alrite I was thinking over $\Bbb C$... but still a silly mistake.

Comment: Note that it is not a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.